# Find first row in data table with unique critera

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a data table in Microsoft Access with two columns:

```
+-----+-------------+
| Row | Status      |
+-----+-------------+
| 1   | In-Progress |
| 2   | In-Progress |
| 3   | In-Progress |
| 4   | TBR         |
| 5   | TBR         |
| 6   | TBR         |
+-----+-------------+
```

I am needing to query the table such that the query will return row 4. I want to know what is the first row in my data table where the status is TBR. Very new to coding in VB.

```
Public Function FindFirstActiveRow() As Integer
    Dim inum As Integer
    inum = 1

    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim query As String = "Select [ROW] From Table3 where [STATUS]='TBR', AND [ROW]= (select MIN(ROW) from table 3);"
    Dim dbsource As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Docs\PRODUCTION\Shop Manager\Shop_Manager\Shop_Manager\Database2.accdb;")
    Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        myreader.Read()
        FindFirstActiveRow = Val(myreader("ROW"))

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Pull Data from Table3")
        FindFirstActiveRow = 1
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible methods:

```sql
select min(table3.row) from table3 where table3.status = 'TBR'
```

```sql
select top 1 table3.row from table3 where table3.status = 'TBR' order by table3.row
```